# How to install quantum computation language on mac os x?

Tags: c++, macos, qcl

I am trying to install QCL 0.6.3 (available from http://tph.tuwien.ac.at/~oemer/qcl.html) on mac os 10.7.2. I have developer tools installed and can do basic programming in c but I don't know a lot about makefiles and such.

The installation instructions are below:

> Besides the usual C++ development tools, you will need to have flex,
>   bison and (optionally) GNU readline installed on your system.
>
> Untar the source package, then cd to the QCL directory, edit the
>   Makefile for your needs and type make  make install
>
> This will, by default, install the binary qcl to /usr/local/bin and
>   the QCL include files to /usr/local/lib/qcl.
>
> For plotting support, libplotter (the C++ bindings of of GNU libplot)
>   is required. GNU libplot is part of the the GNU plotutils.
>
> Since version 0.4.3, QCL also includes support for the TeXmacs
>   mathematical text editor. Recent TeXmacs distributions (1.0.0.6 or
>   newer) already provide the necessary interfaces, so no additional
>   installation is required.

I think that flex and bison are automatically in mac os x?  Not sure about readline or libplotter?

When I type make I receive back an error:

```
g++ -c  -Wall -O2 -g -DQCL_DEBUG -DQC_DEBUG -DQCL_PLOT -DQCL_USE_READLINE -DQCL_IRQ -Iqc -DDEF_INCLUDE_PATH="\"/usr/local/lib/qcl\""   -c -o error.o error.cc
error.cc: In function ‘void initialize_readline()’:
error.cc:39: error: ‘rl_unbind_key’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [error.o] Error 1
```

Any help, general hints, or specific instructions would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you "edit the Makefile for your needs", as per the instructions ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment Paul. When I did some more mucking around I found that editing the makefile did allow me to compile the program. I commented out the plotting support and the readline support sections of the makefile. Then it ran fine and seems to help with